# Emailing Preselected HTML Inputs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I am trying to figure out how to write some code that will take inputs chosen from a dropdown and preselect them so that an individual can just copy the code after it is generated. I currently have 6 attributes a person needs to choose and at the end a part number is generated at the bottom. Ideally, I would want to either have the code that is generated be sent to an email that can be sent to my company for an RFQ or have the inputs in the boxes below preselected so that the user only needs to right click and all 6 boxes get copied, which they can then post into forms, emails, etc.

I am having an issue doing that with my code. My current code for the form and page format is here:

```
<div style="width: 900px; float: left; margin-left: 30px;"><h1>Request a Quote</h1>
<div style="width: 300px; float: left; padding-right:30px;">
<h4 style="line-height:24px;">Please complete the form at the right to contact a representative regarding your request.</h4> 
</div>
<div style="width: 500px; float: left; padding: 20px; background-color: #eee;">
<div>
 <body>
  <form id="example" name="example">
     <b>Sensor Type</b><br>
    <select id="sensor" onchange="updateText('sensor')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="J">J</option>
     <option value="K">K</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
    <b>Voltage</b><br>
<select id="voltage" onchange="updateText('voltage')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="120V">120V</option>
    <option value="240V">240V</option>
</select>
<br>
 <br>
<b>Amps</b><br>
<select id="amps" onchange="updateText('amps')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<b>Channels</b><br>
  <select id="channels" onchange="updateText('channels')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<b>Sensor Connector</b><br>
 <select id="connector" onchange="updateText('connector')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="ML2">NEMA ML2 Mini Twist Lock (Standard)</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
    <b>Thermocouple</b><br>
 <select id="thermocouple" onchange="updateText('thermocouple')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="J">JType</option>
    <option value="K">KType</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

    <br />
    <input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="sensorText" /> -     <input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="voltageText" /> - <input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="ampsText" /> - <input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="channelsText" /> - <input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="connectorText" /> - <input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="thermocoupleText" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function updateText(type) { 
 var id = type+'Text';
 document.getElementById(id).value = document.getElementById(type).value;
}
</script>
</body>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If possible I am trying to achieve this with HTML or Javascript. I can expand on anything if needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Take a look at JavaScript's `join()`. However, I would advise using a server-side language to send e-mails.

Comment: For this `I` would use AJAX to post the form data to a php page and have that PHP email. If you want to look further into php then you will want to look into your hosting account for SMTP details to send emails via PHP. 
Try breaking your question down, use ajax to post the form data to php and then have the php return the data back, once you have this in place you can then move onto putting the data into email format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have edit your form a bit to try to reach your expectation

```html
<div style="width: 900px; float: left; margin-left: 30px;"><h1>Request a Quote</h1>
<div style="width: 300px; float: left; padding-right:30px;">
<h4 style="line-height:24px;">Please complete the form at the right to contact a representative regarding your request.</h4> 
</div>
<div style="width: 500px; float: left; padding: 20px; background-color: #eee;">
<div>
 <body>
  <form id="example" name="example">
     <b>Sensor Type</b><br>
    <select id="sensor" onchange="updateText('sensor')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="J">J</option>
     <option value="K">K</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
    <b>Voltage</b><br>
<select id="voltage" onchange="updateText('voltage')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="120V">120V</option>
    <option value="240V">240V</option>
</select>
<br>
 <br>
<b>Amps</b><br>
<select id="amps" onchange="updateText('amps')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<b>Channels</b><br>
  <select id="channels" onchange="updateText('channels')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<b>Sensor Connector</b><br>
 <select id="connector" onchange="updateText('connector')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="ML2">NEMA ML2 Mini Twist Lock (Standard)</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
    <b>Thermocouple</b><br>
 <select id="thermocouple" onchange="updateText('thermocouple')">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="J">JType</option>
    <option value="K">KType</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

    <br />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="sensorText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="voltageText" /> 
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="ampsText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="channelsText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="connectorText" />
<input type="hidden" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="thermocoupleText" />
    
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="1" size="1" id="completeText" style="width: 300px;" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function updateText(type) { 
 var id = type+'Text';
 var endValue;
 var inputValue = document.getElementById(type).value;
 
 document.getElementById(id).value = inputValue;
 
 endValue = document.getElementById("sensorText").value;
 if(document.getElementById("voltageText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("voltageText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("ampsText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("ampsText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("channelsText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("channelsText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("connectorText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("connectorText").value;
 }
 if(document.getElementById("thermocoupleText").value != ""){
   endValue = endValue+"-"+document.getElementById("thermocoupleText").value;
 }
 document.getElementById("completeText").value = endValue;
}
</script>
</body>
</div>
```

i had set the main inputs to hidden and than create a main input where the js will add the text of the hidden input so the user can easily copy it.

I wrote the javascript in an easy way there will be probably other way to reach the same result without force listing each input in an **if** condition

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes everything very easy and works perfect for our website! I cant thank you enough!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider joining the different inputs into one input. As far as I can tell there is unfortunately no way to select text from multiple inputs simultaneously.

Maybe a long input for a nice design:

```
<input type="text" size="40" id="txtcode" style="letter-spacing: 5px;"/>
```

And the code should be straight forward; simply concat all the different values into one, with a dash in between.

```
<script>
    var types = ['sensor', 'voltage', 'amps', 'channels', 'connector', 'thermocouple'];

    function updateText(type) {
        var text = '';
        for (var i in types) {
            if (i != 0) text += '-';
            text += document.getElementById(types[i]).value;
        }
        document.getElementById('txtcode').value = text;
        document.getElementById('txtcode').select();
    }
</script>
```

Notice that to "pre-select" the text from the input field you can use `document.getElementById('txtcode').select();`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dx24dkkw/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these other people's suggestions for formulating the body of the email.  However, while you certainly can do AJAX to send the email, you might just need to have the user send it themselves using the default email client.  For this just use window.open():

```
window.open("mailto:myname@somedomain.com?Subject=My%20Test&Body=This%20is%20my%20test%20email.");
```